# Proceed to checkout redirects to empty cart page

Tags: checkout, cart, magento2.2.3

When I double click on "Proceed to Checkout", it's redirecting me to an empty cart page but the mini-cart still seems to show a product.

If i add an another product, the mini-cart displays only the new products which I have added. I suspect that this error is because of cookie. Is this is a bug in Magento? Please comment with your suggestion.

**Version: Magento 2.2.3**

Comment: There are many issues posted on github related to minicart updation in Magento 2.

Comment: Yes @MohitKumarArora, I did check and verified. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15434